# IntelliJ IDEa 2018.2 highlights var lambda parameter as error using JDK 11

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-lombok-plugin, java-11

Tested on Oracle JDK 11 and latest (as of now) available version of IntelliJ IDEa (IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.4). Project language level is Java 11.

**Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(List.of("AAA", "BBB", "CCC")
            .stream()
            .map((@NonNull var s) -> s.toLowerCase())
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

**Output**

```
[aaa, bbb, ccc]
```

Everything compiles and runs fine, but editor shows compile-time error:

[image]

Is [JEP-323](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/323) (Local-Variable Syntax for Lambda Parameters) not yet supported or it's a bug?

Comment: Not really an answer but why would you need the `var` anyway? `s -> s.toLowerCase()` should work as well. Or even a method reference.

Comment: @M.Deinum `String::toLowerCase` is better, but this issue is going to become popular as people start switching to Java 11

Comment: If you read the JEP, you'll see that the only real reason for adding `var` for lambda parameters is so that you may annotate it without explicitly declaring the type. Given you don't use any annotations, what use is `var` adding?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Well if it was a case in which you needed the `var` here, here it isn't really necessary.

Comment: The point is that it's a legal Java 11 structure whereas IntelliJ (Lombok plugin to be precise) thinks it's not. I will add annotation so the code will make more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have this error, you most likely have the Lombok plugin installed. It is a Lombok plugin inspection bug.

Disabling the following inspection will fix the problem:

**File | Settings | Editor | Probable bugs | Lombok annotations inspection**

Also inspection can be implicitly suppressed.
[image]

The issue in Lombok-intellij-plugin project has been created:

https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/531

Answer (score 2):

You should turn off the Lombok annotations inspection until they fix the issue.

[image]
[image]